Cannot borrow *self as immutable, but I cannot find a way around
So I have the above error in line 17, that I understand, but don't find a good way around:
struct Node {
    node_type: NodeType
}

enum NodeType {
    Inner([Box<Node>; 16]),
    Leaf(Vec<usize>)
}

impl Node {
    fn foo(&mut self) {
        match &mut self.node_type {
            NodeType::Leaf(_content) => {
                // Mutate content
            },
            NodeType::Inner(children) => {
                let index = self.compute_index();
                let child = &mut children[index];
                child.foo();
            }
        }
    }

    fn compute_index(&self) -> usize {
        // compute something
        0
    }
}

Playground
I need self to be mutable, to mutate its content in the Leaf case. I could copy the code from compute_index() into my foo() function, but it would make the foo() function unnecessarily long and the code inside the compute_index() seems like a separate semantical unit on its own.
I could also move the call to compute_index() above the match statement, but I don't need to execute it in all match arms, so this would cause unnecessary computations in that case and doesn't seem right either.
I thought about this for quite some time, but cannot figure out a way to get rid of this error without making my code bad.
Does anyone have ideas on how to get rid of the error without making the code bad?

Does compute_index() depends on children?

No, it does not

Then you can have it take only the necessary fields instead of the whole self. Alternatively, if it makes more sense, split a NonChildren struct out of Node, and make compute_index() a method of NonChildren.

Can you shuffle the things around to compute the index before acquiring a mutable borrow?
impl Node {
    fn foo(&mut self) {
        if let NodeType::Leaf(_content) = &mut self.node_type {
            // Mutate content
            _content.push(42);
        } else {
            let index = self.compute_index();
            if let NodeType::Inner(children) = &mut self.node_type {
                let child = &mut children[index];
                child.foo();
            }
        }
    }

    fn compute_index(&self) -> usize {
        // compute something
        0
    }
}


Yes, that works well. The second if let seems a bit unnecessary, since you already know its an Inner, but this seems like the best solution, thanks! :)

The problem of match is that it keeps the borrow for the whole body. You can maybe also keep your match as is, and conditionally compute the index before match with let index = if let NodeType::Inner(_) = self.node_type { self.compute_index() } else { 0 }; , and use the index only in one branch of match, but this kinda leaks incapsulation

True, but I prefer your original solution, because I don't like declaring variables in a wider scope than they are used/needed in.
